# Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected when using Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm facing a weird problem. When I'm trying to debug my app on Windows Phone Emulator I'm getting this error:

Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.

However Emulator is launched, the app is deployed correctly and I'm able to debug it without any problems. I'm writing this question because this error is a bit annoying. I'm using the same settings on another machine and everything works fine there.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate / Win 8.1 with settings like below:

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the entire screen when you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem. I have 3 Windows Phone projects, one of them (which was in fact not marked as a startup one) was targeting the physical device, and that caused the problem. Problem was solved by switching Target device in project properties -> Debug to emulator.